# ListItems doubles in number(duplicated) in Custom ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am using a custom `ListView` which gets doubled in number(duplicate listItems) when I go to previous activity and again come to that ListViewActivity.

I can see where the problem occurs. When I go to the ListViewActivity for the first time everything is fine where the listitems are added to the `ArrayList` and the adapter is set. But when I go to the previous activity and come again to the ListViewActivity, the previously set listitems are still present in the `Adapter` and again the listitems are set when the process goes through `setAdapter()` which is causing the duplication of listitems.

I have came across many solutions like using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, clearing the `ArrayList`, `setAdapter(null)`, etc. None of these solutions helped me.

I guess the solution is clearing the `Adapter`and the `ArrayList` and refreshing the `Adapter`. But I don't know how and where exactly to do it.

Here is my code:

This is the data recieving class in the LoadingActivity.java

```
private class CategoriesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Double>{

     String res="";
     String curState ="";
     String httppoststr="";
     boolean isNxtActivity=false;

     @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        postData(params[0]);
        return null;

     }
     protected void onPostExecute(Double Result)
     {  
        if(isNxtActivity)
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, ListItemsActivity.class);
            if(curState.equals(Constants.STATE_GET_STOCK_ITEMS))
            {
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.STOCK_ITEMS_LIST, listOfItems);
                intent.putExtra("curState", Constants.STATE_GET_STOCK_ITEMS);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.CUSTOMER_ID, customerId);
                LoadingActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    public void postData(String ValueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.GatewayUrl);
        try
        {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(ValueIWantToSend);
            curState = json.getString("curState");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(ValueIWantToSend);
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httppoststr =httppost.toString();
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            res = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(res);
            String state = jsonobj.getString(Constants.STATE);

            if(Constants.RESPONSE_SUCCESS.equals(state.toLowerCase()))
            {
                isNxtActivity =true;
                if(curState.equals(Constants.STATE_GET_STOCK_ITEMS))
                {
                    JSONArray itemsListJsonArray=new JSONArray(); 
                    itemsListJsonArray=jsonobj.getJSONArray(Constants.STOCK_ITEMS_LIST);

                    for(int i=0;i<itemsListJsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        String itemslist=itemsListJsonArray.getString(i);
                        listOfItems.add(itemslist.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
private String[] arrayOfNames;
private String[] arrayOfImageUrls;

ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listOfImageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_items);

    itemsList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsList);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    listOfItems = extras.getStringArrayList(Constants.STOCK_ITEMS_LIST); //The duplication occurs here while getting the data from the LoadingActivity when visiting this activity for the second time.

    arrayOfNames = new String[listOfNames.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<listOfNames.size();i++)
    {
        arrayOfNames[i]=listOfNames.get(i);
    }

    arrayOfImageUrls = new String[listOfImageUrls.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<listOfImageUrls.size();i++)
    {
        arrayOfImageUrls[i]=listOfImageUrls.get(i);
    } 

    listItemadapter = new CustomListItemsAdapter(this, arrayOfNames, arrayOfImageUrls); 
    itemsList.setAdapter(listItemadapter);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[] arrayOfNames;

public CustomListItemsAdapter(ListItemsActivity listItemsActivity, String[] itemsName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    context=listItemsActivity;
    arrayOfNames = itemsName;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayOfNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
   private TextView itemName;
   private ImageView itemImage;
}

 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;     

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_content, parent, false);

        holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);       

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemName.setText(arrayOfNames[position]);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ListItemsAsyncTask listAsync = new ListItemsAsyncTask();
    Drawable drawableIcon = listAsync.loadImageFromServer(arrayOfImageUrls[position]);
    holder.itemImage.setImageDrawable(drawableIcon);

 return convertView;
}

private class ListItemsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    String httpPostStr, res;
    Boolean NextActivity = false;

    public Drawable loadImageFromServer(String url) 
    {
       try {
          InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
          Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
          return drawable;
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace(); 
          return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions???

**UPDATE:** I have found the problem behind this duplication. The second time when I come to the ListViewActivity the duplication occurs in the Bundle from which I get the data for the `ListView` and its contents.

Now I need a solution to stop the duplication in the Bundle. I have mentioned the duplication occuring line with a comment in ListViewActivity.java

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @Nisarg i have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function **setAdapter()** only once in onCreate() , because onCreate() is called only when the activity first starts , second time when you start the activity onCreate() is not called , but if you destroy the activity , then onCreate() will be called again , make sure you are not destroying the activity .

Comment: As per your suggestion, I already have setAdapter() only once in `onCreate()` and I am not destroying anything. Are you sure that onCreate() is called only when the activity first starts and the second time when I start the activity onCreate() is not called?

Comment: yes oncreate() is called only once and subsequent methods onstart() and onresume() are called then after whenever second time you visit the activity , post the onresume() code ....

Comment: `    @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  listOfItems.clear();
  listItemadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 } `

Answer (score 0):

probably you are loading list in `onResume` and you are adding items to list attached to adapter and here you have duplicate each time.

Proper way is:
load data in `onResume`, make sure you are not adding duplicates to list, or clear list before adding data. then after fill list - check if adapter was initialised and attached if already initialised then add data to list and simple make on adapter `.notifyDataSetChanged()` if not initialised then initialise it with attaching your list to it.

Make attention when you attached list to adapter then you cannot change pointer to your list variable:

```
yourList = downloadedList; // Wrong way you will override the pointer to list in adapter
```

must be something like:

```
yourList.clear();
yourList.addAll(downloadedList); // Correct way
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Are your sure that this code should be in `onResume()` ?. Because whenever I go to ListViewActivity `onCreate()` is only called where I found this on debugging.

Comment: onCreate() called when you create activity, onResume() works each time activity become active (foreground). If you don't need to reload data each time activity become active then you can move it to onCreate() also make sure you are downloading your data in async task coz you will get UI stuck on data update

Comment: I did your suggested code in `onResume()` but no changes. Still listitems are duplicated on going to that activity second time.

Comment: how you get data to "listOfNames"? Also as i see wrong using of async task

Comment: The data for `listOfNames` are recieved from the server and passed to this ListViewActivity through a LoadingActivity.

Comment: show me code where you initialise listOfItems in loading.

Comment: I solved it by clearing the listOfItems bro. listOfItems was initialized as `ArrayList<String> listOfItems  = new ArryaList<String>();`. The problem was in listOfItems which was not cleared. Thats the reason of duplication of listitems in the `ListView`.

Comment: yes thats why I asked to show me this code ) nice work )